# python_terraform : can't disable apply confirmation

Tags: python, terraform

I'm encountering an issue while using `python_terraform` to apply changes to my Terraform configuration automatically. Specifically, even when I include the `auto_approve=True` flag in the `terraform.apply()` function call, it still prompts me for confirmation. Below is my code snippet:

```
python
```

```
from python_terraform import Terraform

# Initialize Terraform
t = Terraform()
variables = {'a': 'b'}
print("Initializing Terraform...")
return_code, stdout, stderr = terraform.init()
if return_code == 0:
    print("Terraform initialized successfully")

# Show state
terraform.show()

# Apply Terraform changes
print("Applying Terraform changes...")
return_code, stdout, stderr = terraform.apply(
    auto_approve=True,  # supposed to auto-approve but doesn't seem to work
    var=variables,
    lock=False,
    capture_output=False,
    input=False
)
if stdout and stderr:
    print(stdout.decode('utf-8'))  # Print stdout
    print(stderr.decode('utf-8'))  # Print stderr

print("done successfully")
```

However, when I run this script, it still prompts me for confirmation with the message:

```
Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.
  Enter a value: #if i tap "yes" it works
```

Comment: known bug: https://github.com/beelit94/python-terraform/issues/84

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There is a small bug in `terraform_python` script. To solve it, just locate where `terraform_python` is installed. In Ubuntu you can use the command:

```
pip show python_terraform
```

after that, locate this line inside __init__.py:

```
default['auto-approve'] = (skip_plan == True)
```

replace with this:

```
default['auto_approve'] = (skip_plan == True)
```

Problem solved. Hope someone will find this useful.